# Get the image name from NSURL UIImagepicker Controller iOS 9

Tags: ios

I have picked image from UIImagePickerController, after that i get the info dictionary of its delegate method. I want to get image name from NSURL Please suggest code for iOS 9, because ALAsset library code has been deprecated to get image name.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

Comment: I think it will help:
`[[imageURL.absoluteString lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];`

Answer (score 0):

import asset library

### Try This, You will get image name in cstmGetUploadImageName method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    //    selected image
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.img_profilepic.image = chosenImage;

    //    NSString *setimageName;
    // get the ref url
    NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    // define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
        NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
        [self cstmGetUploadImageName:[imageRep filename]];

    };

    // get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];


    //    upload image method
    //[self cstmUploadImage:chosenImage withName:@"sdf"];
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}


-(void)cstmGetUploadImageName:(NSString *)filename{
    NSString  *tempFileName = filename;
    NSLog(@"%@",tempFileName);
}
```

Comment: ALAsset is deprecated in ios 9

Comment: Yeah, but you can get what you want